# Javascript Booking Year Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for year calendar with select range functions, but i don't found this. And I decided customize Bootstrap Year Calendar - http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/

And I'm stuck, my customised version is on http://ngrdanjski.com/calendar/
and I'm looking for help!

I added:

1. All days are disabled by default.
2. You can added Price periods, in this dates period you have enabled booking.
3. I want to add option when first click on the day it's first day of booking range, and second click is last day of booking range. Right now when click on day you have enable start date/first day, but when you click second time on day when you want to select end date, it's again start/first date. I wan't to have function to select start and end date. First click on day is start and second is end.

Code for current behavior is:

```
if(this.options.enableRangeSelection) {


                cells.mousedown(function (e) {
                    if(e.which == 1) 
                    {
                        var currentDate = _this._getDate($(this));
                        //console.log(currentDate);

                        if(_this.options.allowOverlap || _this.getEvents(currentDate).length == 0)
                        {
                            _this._mouseDown = true;
                            _this._rangeStart = _this._rangeEnd = currentDate;
                            _this._refreshRange();
                        }
                    }
                });




                cells.mouseenter(function (e) {
                    //console.log(e);
                    if (_this._mouseDown) 
                    {
                        var currentDate = _this._getDate($(this));

                        if(!_this.options.allowOverlap)
                        {
                            var newDate =  new Date(_this._rangeStart.getTime());

                            if(newDate < currentDate) 
                            {
                                var nextDate = new Date(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), newDate.getDate() + 1);
                                while(newDate < currentDate) 
                                {
                                    if(_this.getEvents(nextDate).length > 0)
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                                    nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate() + 1);
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                var nextDate = new Date(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), newDate.getDate() - 1);
                                while(newDate > currentDate)
                                {
                                    if(_this.getEvents(nextDate).length > 0)
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - 1);
                                    nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate() - 1);
                                }
                            }

                            currentDate = newDate;
                        }

                        var oldValue = _this._rangeEnd;
                        _this._rangeEnd = currentDate;

                        if (oldValue.getTime() != _this._rangeEnd.getTime()) 
                        {
                            _this._refreshRange();
                        }
                    }
                });


                /* $(window).mouseup(function (e) {
                    if (_this._mouseDown) 
                    {
                        _this._mouseDown = false;
                        _this._refreshRange();

                        var minDate = _this._rangeStart < _this._rangeEnd ? _this._rangeStart : _this._rangeEnd;
                        var maxDate = _this._rangeEnd > _this._rangeStart ? _this._rangeEnd : _this._rangeStart;

                        _this._triggerEvent('selectRange', { 
                            startDate: minDate, 
                            endDate: maxDate,
                            events: _this.getEventsOnRange(minDate, new Date(maxDate.getFullYear(), maxDate.getMonth(), maxDate.getDate() + 1))
                        });
                    }
                }); */


            }
```

URL: https://ngrdanjski.com/calendar/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.js
Full version: https://codepen.io/NGrdanjski/pen/bQGdRb
I don't have skill for this functionality, please help.

Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code a bit. I understand that you want to set two dates, the start and the end of the range, and all that happens in two clicks. I also added a check if the second date is after the first one, if it's not they will swap places, so the earlier date is the rangeStart. The dates are stored in rangeStart and rangeEnd:

Edit: [here's a pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQObwG?editors=1111)

```
        cells.mousedown(function (e) {
                if(e.which == 1)
                {
                    var currentDate = _this._getDate($(this));
                    //console.log(currentDate);

                    if(_this.options.allowOverlap || _this.getEvents(currentDate).length == 0)
                    {
            if(!_this._mouseDown) {
              _this._mouseDown = true;
              _this._rangeStart = _this._rangeEnd = currentDate;
              _this._refreshRange();
            }
            else {
              _this._mouseDown = false;
              _this._rangeEnd = currentDate;

              if(_this._rangeEnd.getTime() < _this._rangeStart.getTime()) {
                var tempDate = _this._rangeEnd;
                _this._rangeEnd = _this._rangeStart;
                _this._rangeStart = tempDate;
              }
            //  _this._refreshRange();
            }

                    }

        if(_this._rangeStart != _this._rangeEnd) {
          console.log(_this._rangeStart.getDate() + ',' + _this._rangeEnd.getDate());
        }

                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes! This is it! Tnx a lot!